# Convert custom objects to int with explicit base

Tags: python, integer, python-3.10

Let's say we have the following class:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = "12"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bar
    
    def __int__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("inside __int__")
        return int(self.bar, *args, **kwargs)


a = Foo()
print(int(a))
# -> inside __int__
# -> 12
```

The result of printing this is as you would expect. However if we try:

```
print(int(a, 10))   # or any other valid base instead of 10
```

the following exception is raised:

```
TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base
```

Also, `inside __int__` is not printed meaning that `a.__int__` is not called. Is there any special method which would allow specifying a base in the `int()` call or do I just have to live with this behavior?

Even more interesting (and more in the direction of what I want to do) is the following:

```
class Foo(str):   # subclass of str and excepts argument in constructor
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar

    def __int__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return int(self.bar, *args, **kwargs)


a = Foo("12")
print(int(a), int(a, 10))
# -> 12 12
# Actually works

a.bar = "34"
print(int(a), int(a, 10))
# -> 34 12
# what?
```

My assumption on this one is that `int(num, base)` uses `num.__getnewargs__()`. Either way, is there any way to get around these examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is specifically called out in [the documentation of `int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

> If *x* is not a number or if *base* is given, then *x* must be a
> string, `bytes`, or `bytearray` instance representing an integer
> literal in radix *base*.

The `__int__` "magic method" (or `__index__`, `__trunc__` which are used as fallbacks) is only invoked when the `base` argument is **not** provided.

Comment: Yes, I've read the documentation on this. So in other words, it's up to me to say `int(a.bar, some_base)` instead, right?

Comment: @Mr_HxID that could be one way to handle it, yes. Or e.g. if the base was a property of the instance the `__int__` implementation could `return(self.bar, self.base)` and be used with the single-arg `int`.

Comment: Ok, I'll probably do something similar to this then. Still, I find it kind of silly of python to place such a restriction on the multi-arg `int`. But thanks for your quick reply.